# What if we start build max heap procedure from 1 to heap.length/2 rather than heap.length/2 to 1

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

First of all ,this is not a homework question.
I was studying CLRS when i came across a query that what would happen if we start build heap procedure in reverse way(form 1 to a.length/2).I figured out by solving it on some heaps and this gave wrong results(as expected) but still i m not able to fully satisfy myself without a proof that this mere verification by examples is correct.I tried to prove it mathematically but i m a newbie in this field of proofs so i do not know where to start.How do i prove it by maths?

Any suggestions on how to approach such types of proofs in a mathematical way  will also be greatly helpful for me.thanks.

Comment: This question seems a better fit for the Computer Science site than for here. Also, the heap is usually built by trickling-down each element from heap.length/2 down to 1: the other elements do not need to be trickled down. If you build from 1 to heap.length/2 you would need to trickle up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Computer Science rather than programming.

Comment: ok  @RoryDaulton  I got that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original solution you go from length/2 and you push nodes down. The thing is that between length/2+1 and end you have only what would be leaf nodes in the heap. Since they have height 1 (single nodes) each of them are correct heaps. What the algorithm is doing at each step is to create a new heap where the root is some random value but the left and right subtrees are valid heaps (the precoditions for the push operation to generate a correct heap).

When you go the other direction you push the first node but it's subtrees are not valid heaps (they are whatever was in the array). So the push operation is not guaranteed to work correctly.

If you really want to build the heap from 1, you need to consider only the nodes you've touched as part of the correct heap and what the algorithm is doing is to add a leaf and fix the heap (via a pop operation). Note that in this case you can't stop at length/2, you need to go all the way to the end.

In theory both solutions are O(NlogN) but doing it with push operation will yield a smaller constant (since you only do it for half the nodes) and will tend to run faster on average.

For the proof just construct the input where the push operation on the first node will not do anything because of nodes 2 and 3 are larger/smaller. It's easy to see that it doesn't mean that node 1 is the max/min of the array.

Say you are doing a min heap and your input is `[1, 2, 3, 0, ...]`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.Now i have 2 doubts.first about the order of solution you said(O(nlogn))  but i think the bottom up procedure of build heap i.e from a.length/2 to 1 takes linear time.second would it be correct while proving question inductively to take the base case that a heap with one node is a max heap(or min as said) and then progressing further........